# Is it possible to find the person who connected remotely to my PC via VNC?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, home-networking, event-log, tightvnc

TL;DR: My computer got remotely accessed and I want to know what the person did on it.

---

The details: I started tinkering with remote connection because I wanted to remotely work on my home PC from school and not use my phone data because it is limited.

I used 2 apps during the process, Parsec and TightVNC.

I first tried the normal port for those application but none worked (Parsec didn't worked at all for other reasons I don't know) and I started using port 8080 which was known for allowing to connect outside by my comrades.

My mistake lies in the fact that I disabled the password (I know it's stupid but it's done) during my many tests and forgot to activate it back.

Tonight, after starting my computer and logging in, I got on my phone and after around 10 to 15 minutes saw my mouse moving on its own. I saw it accessing the remote desktop parameters on Windows 10 and it probably activated it but I don't know what happened at all.

I turned off my computer as soon as I could and disconnected the ethernet cable before restarting to check if it installed something. I also removed every NAT configuration from my router.

Now, I want to know if there is a way to find the culprit either by reading some logs or something and know what he did?

I will wipe the computer whatsoever and do a clean install (might change OS at the same time, I don’t know).

Comment: @John thank you for the quick response. i knew iwould probably never find him but still wanted to give it a try. do you have some tips on securing the computer ?

Comment: Last time I checked, VNC was limited to an 8-char password (its been some years so be sure to check; VNC wont tell you the password is too long, it will just ignore any characters after the 8th, leaving you with the illusion your password is longer). if that is still the case, then exposing VNC even with a password is not sufficiently secure.

Comment: “Tonight, after starting my computer and logging in, I got on my phone and after around 10 to 15 minutes saw my mouse moving on its own. I saw it accessing the remote desktop parameters on Windows 10 and it probably activated it but I don't know what happened at all.” Do you know exactly when this happened? If so, I would check the VNC logs for that time period and look for something that might give you a clue.

Comment: @FrankThomas do you know about safer alternatives ? i still want to be able to work remotely across multiple OS for school.
I found in the windows event logs that some people tried to log hundreds of time and got this : `Invalid format of the RFB version message` which kept me alive until my mistake.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I found out the exact time when this happened through Windows event viewer. Unfortunately, tightvnc disable logs by default so i can't find anything on this side. I am still searching in the Windows event viewer for clues about what the person (or more probably script) did but I am not sure I'll find anything.

Comment: We don't do product recommendations here, but speaking generically, the best way to secure VNC is not expose it to the Internet, and to use VPN or SSH tunnel to connect to the network from remote. Another (not free) alternative might be a software product that uses server infrastructure on the Internet to enable reverse tunnels you can use to access the device, though those will probably not function for all OS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the person on the other end accessed your computer using VNC it is impossible to tell what he/she did.

VNC runs (in most cases) under your own user-account. Because of that there is no way to distinguish what happened via VNC from what you yourself have been doing on the computer.

There may be some logging in the Windows Event viewer or a VNC related log-file that lists when the last logon was and from were, but this is highly dependend on which VNC variant you used and how it was configured.

Comment: thank you. I found out that logs where disabled by default on my vnc so I could not find anything. I tried watching inside windows logs through the event viewer and found out i can see every ip address which logged in or at least tried. i have hundreds of request from the same guy and i found the ips of the potential culprit. don't know what to do with it, will probably do nothing but knowing it made me feel better. I will continue to search for windows parameter logs and changed the person probably did.

Comment: @LouisNoël If you have the ip's (the address and the date/time when that ip logged in) and these ip's originate from the same ISP (ip-range registration databases are public and list the party responsible for any given public ip-address range), you could consider making an abuse complaint with that ISP. (Each ISP has contact information as well.) Doubtful if the ISP will act on it. They might if they get enough complaints about that same customer.